# How do namespaces actually work in Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

With a single socket, I need to switch between two namespaces.

```
socket.on('ns1', function() {
  socket.join('ns1');
});

socket.on('ns2', function() {
  socket.join('ns2');
});
```

How would I disconnect from the namespace `ns1` which I've already connected to and join the namespace `ns2`? And vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved with:

```
socket.leave('ns1');
socket.join('ns2');
```

and vice-versa.